# Send the Form to another Domain's page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms

I have a form with lots of data.

There is a `Submit` button.

Upon clicking it, `asp:validators` will do their `client validation`.

And One or two `Server Validators` will do their `server validation` on the server side.

If everything is `validated`, a Thank you page will be shown, an email will be sent and the data will be stored into the database.

After that, there will be another server which needs the same data to store in another database.

So, my question is how to transfer the data to another domain, another URL.

Somebody wrote that it could be done by using 2 `Submit` button, one to perform validation and other normal functionality  then to click the second button.

The second button will post to another page using `PostBackURL`.

Is that the correct way or is there any better to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have all data validated on your server, you can issue a [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to the final URL. You don't want to rely on the client for this.

Comment: Hi I have managed to use `HttpWebRequest` to send to another page. But Which method do I use to grab the data on that page?